# printf is only printing "1537" rather than the value of the integer

Tags: c, printf

I'm just now learning programming, so this might seem a tiresome question. But when I try to print the value of an integer, it prints "1537" instead. Here is the function, feel free to scrutinize.

```
void compare(void) {
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int num4;
int smallest;

printf("Please enter four integers:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);

num1 = smallest;
if (num2 < smallest)
    num2 = smallest;
if (num3 < smallest)
    num3 = smallest;
if (num4 < smallest)
    num4 = smallest;

printf("%d is the smallest\n", smallest);

}
```

Comment: Assignment works the other way around in C (and C++ and Java and Perl and python and PHP and...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to assign the values to `smallest` rather than from it.

Change it to

```
smallest=num1;
if (num2 < smallest)
    smallest= num2;
if (num3 < smallest)
    smallest=num3;
if (num4 < smallest)
    smallest=num4;
```

~Sometimes its tough to catch the smallest mistakes~ :)

Comment: the `smallest` mistake 'eh?

Answer (score 3):

You don't initialize smallest.  Actually, you don't write to it at all, anywhere.